# What is the importance of fate line in our hands?

Tags: astrology

I have heard that our life works on the fate line, What do our scriptures say about fate line?

Comment: I have read Samudrik Vidya. It is written in there one who has strong fate line they' get deceived by people more often because of their nature of trusting anyone easily. But at the same time this doesn't stop them going further.